# Program prints an extra row with value 10 after each input

Tags: c, printf, getchar

I've got this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while ( ( c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%d %c\n", c, c);

    return 1; 
}
```

However for some reason when executing i get an extra value ten at the end:

```
a
97 a
10 

b
98 b
10 

abc
97 a
98 b
99 c
10
```

What is the value 10 and where does it come from? How do I stop it from occurring?

Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while ( ( c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if ( isprint (c))
        {
            printf("%d %c\n", c, c);
        }
    }

    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: `10` is the ascii code for newline (`\n`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the newline you enter for the input. It has the ASCII value 10.

Here are three ways of "stopping" it:

1. Add an `if` check in the loop to check for it, and print only when it's not a newline.
2. Use `fgets` to read one complete line at a time, remove the newline from the string (`fgets` adds it) and loop over the string and print each character.
3. Use `scanf` to read a character. With a leading space in the format it will skip whitespace like newlines.

The first method can be used to check for unprintable characters as well (see [`isprint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isprint)), and other classes of characters if you want to do special printing for them (look at these [character classification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) functions).

Comment: Ok, so 10 is the ASCII value and the empty row after 10 is the %c for newline?

Comment: Thank you! Using isprint I was able to remove it.